# Diagonal Riemannian metrics with $SU(2)$ isometry

Tags: group-theory, riemannian-geometry

I am undergrad trying to get into $SU(2)$ invariant instanton geometries, and I am very confused about how to formulate a statement in an invariant way.

I know that a general four-dimensional Riemannian metric with $SU(2)$ isometry locally looks like
$$g = d r^2 + h_{ij}(r) \sigma^i \sigma^j \tag{1}$$
where $r$ is some radial coordinate and $\sigma^i$, $i,j=1,2,3$, are left-invariant $SU(2)$ 1-forms. These 1-forms can then be parameterized in coordinate form, if necessary, e.g., $\sigma^3 = d\psi + \cos \theta \,d\phi$ and more complicated expressions for $\sigma^{1},\sigma^{2}$.

I have been working with geometries that have $h_{ij}$ as a diagonal metric, e.g.,
$$h = a^2(r) (\sigma^1)^2 + b^2(r) (\sigma^2)^2 + c^2(r) (\sigma^3)^2 .$$

However, *the diagonality of a metric is a frame dependent choice*, e.g., $SO(2)$ rotation of $\sigma^{1,2}$ will introduce $r$-dependent cross-terms!

**Is there a frame-invariant way of saying that the metric (1) is diagonal?**

P.S. Please correct me if I ask an imprecise question, this is my first question here!

Comment: Your question is fine. Have you thought about a simpler case? What happens with a Riemannian surface? If $g=a(\sigma^1)^2 + b(\sigma^2)^2$, can you rotate the frame and maintain diagonal form of the metric? What condition on $a$ and $b$ do you need?

Comment: @TedShifrin If $a^2 \neq b^2$ then general constant $SO(2)$ rotations will break the diagonal form.. Which is, vice versa, if given an arbitrary metric $g = a_{11} (\sigma^1)^2 + 2 a_{12} \sigma^1\, \sigma^2 + a_{22} (\sigma^2)^2$ where $a_{11,12,22}$ are functions or $r$, it is difficult to check if this metric can be diagonalized by constant rotation..
Is that what you have asked?